# Laravel Eloquent WHERE field=(...) subquery

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have three tables: (Many-To-Many relation between users and wordlists, and userlistrels is connector)

```
users:
id
name

wordlists:
id
name
creator_id

userlistrels:
id
user_id
wordlist_id
```

I want to execute following query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=( SELECT wordlists.creator_id FROM userlistrels JOIN wordlists ON wordlists.id=userlistrels.wordlist_id WHERE userlistrels.user_id=$curr_user )
```

How to write this type of subqueries (`WHERE foo= ( subquery )`) in Laravel interface?
Documentation covers `SELECT * FROM (subquery) WHERE contition`,
 `SELECT * FROM table WHERE (subquery LIMIT 1) = 'foo'`,
but not `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field=(subquery)`

I've tried many approaches, and this is the only one that doesn't throw exception, however it doesn't work:

```
$curr_user = // id of my user
$users = User::where('id', function($query) use($curr_user){
        $query->select('wordlists.creator_id')
            ->from('userlistrels')
            ->join('wordlists', 'wordlists.id', '=', 'userlistrels.wordlist_id')
            ->where('userlistrels.user_id', $curr_user);
    })->get();
```

Could anyone please tell me what's wrong with this code, or how to make this type of subquery?

EDIT:
My SQL query was wrong.
Correct query for what i tried to do is:
`SELECT * FROM users JOIN (SELECT wordlists.creator_id FROM userlistrels JOIN wordlists ON wordlists.id=userlistrels.wordlist_id WHERE userlistrels.user_id=$curr_user) AS nn ON users.id=nn.creator_id;`

And correct laravel code:

```
$users_sub = DB::table('userlistrels')->join('wordlists', 'wordlists.id', '=', 'userlistrels.wordlist_id')->where('userlistrels.user_id', $curr_user)->select('wordlists.creator_id');

        $users = DB::table('users')
            ->joinSub($users_sub, 'tt', function ($join) {
                $join->on('users.id', '=', 'tt.creator_id');
            })->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem comes from your subquery. That subquery will return multiple `creator_id` depends on your database, so there is two solutions.

#### Solution 1:

Use `whereIn` instead of `where`:

```php
User::whereIn('id', function($query) use($curr_user){
        $query->select('wordlists.creator_id')
            ->from('userlistrels')
            ->join('wordlists', 'wordlists.id', '=', 'userlistrels.wordlist_id')
            ->where('userlistrels.user_id', $curr_user);
    })->get();
```

#### Solution 2:

append `limit(1)` after `where('userlistrels.user_id', $curr_user)`:

```php
User::whereIn('id', function($query) use($curr_user){
        $query->select('wordlists.creator_id')
            ->from('userlistrels')
            ->join('wordlists', 'wordlists.id', '=', 'userlistrels.wordlist_id')
            ->where('userlistrels.user_id', $curr_user)
            ->limit(1);
    })->get();
```

Comment: Well I know I can do it like that, but that's not what I want. I need this subquery to return multiple creator_ids, however I realized this can't be done this way, I have to use another JOIN to join the subquery with users table. Sorry, I'm not really experienced in SQL :(  Well I could realise that if it isn't in the docs, then probably it's not possible. Thx for answer.

Comment: Btw correct query for what I tried to do was: `SELECT * FROM users JOIN (SELECT wordlists.creator_id FROM userlistrels JOIN wordlists ON wordlists.id=userlistrels.wordlist_id WHERE userlistrels.user_id=$curr_user) AS t ON users.id=t.creator_id;`